# 2D array through classes in C++

Tags: c++, class

I am new to C++, well programming in general. I am trying to learn syntax in C++ and I am currently trying to print a 6X6 matrix through a class. I have attached the code below. I am supposed to get a 6X6 matrix filled with zeros but instead I am getting some other value. I do not have this problem if I print it directly from main(). Please see the code and out put attached below (matrix c and B)

Thanks,

```
#include <iostream>

class test {
public:
    test();
    ~test() {};

    int c[6][6];

    int print();
};

test::test() {
    int c[6][6] = { 0 };
}

int test::print() {
    for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++) {
            cout << c[r][q] << " ";
        }cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int B[4][4] = { 0 };
    test a;
    a.print();

    std::cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            std::cout << B[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Program's output:

```
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: The member `int c[6][6];` in `test` is uninitialized

Comment: Great! it works if I initialize it c[6][6]={0} with function definition. Shouldn't this also work as I have initialized it under the constructor? I was told to use the constructor for initialization. What am I missing?

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

The immediate problem is that your constructor includes the line

```
int c[6][6] = {0};
```

but, this [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `c`, and therefore, the values you assign do not propagate to the class scope.

**Detecting the Problem**

You could have figured this out easily for yourself... if you'd enabled warnings on your compiler. (You may not have known: use warnings to your advantage in the future!)

By compiling your code with:

```
g++ temp2.cpp -Wall
```

I get the following handy message:

```
temp2.cpp: In constructor ‘test::test()’:
temp2.cpp:15:9: warning: unused variable ‘c’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int c[6][6] = { 0 };
```

Which indicates the exact line that needs attention, though perhaps not the symptoms of the problem (the compiler worries that you don't use `c` locally in this function, but perhaps should have warned about shadowed variables - oh well).

**Improving the Code**

Since you are using C++, you can take advantage of the `std::vector` class to handle memory management of your array. You can also declare your `print` class `const` to prevent any possibility of it changing the values of `c`. Incorporating these changes, along with an accessor method and flat-array indexing gives the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
 public:
  std::vector<int> c;
  int width;
  int height;

  Test() = default;

  Test(int width0, int height0, int init_val=0){
    width  = width0;
    height = height0;
    c.resize(width*height,init_val);
  }

  int operator()(int x, int y) const {
    return c[y*width+x];
  }

  int& operator()(int x, int y) {
    return c[y*width+x];
  }

  void print() const {
    for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
      for(int x=0;x<width;x++)
        std::cout<<operator()(x,y)<<" ";
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
  }
};

int main(){
  Test t(6,6,0);
  t.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `test::test` constuctor is initializing a new local variable and you are thereby assigning a value to a new variable and not your class's.
Removing int before initializing and the size should fix it

Comment: It's not only removing the type specifier `int`, but removing the array size too.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor:

```
test::test() {
    int c[6][6] = {0};
}
```

You are declaring an array named `c` initialized to `0`. However, the class member `c` is not initialized. You probably meant this:

```
test::test() : c{} {
}
```

Or even better, this:

```
class test {
public:
    test() = default;
    ~test() = default;
    int c[6][6] = {};
    int print();
};
```

Comment: Initialization from constructor such as c={0}; results in an error "array type int[6][6] is not assignable" but initializing it as test::test() {
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
   c[i][j]=0;
  }
 }
} works. Is there a better way to initialize it through a constructor? Directly initializing during declaration as you recommended works as well!

Comment: @user6771484 Use the constructor initializer list: `test::test() : c{ /*...*/ } {}`.

Comment: umm... I am still getting the same error. You meant to remove '0' from withing the { } during c initialization of the constructor right?

Comment: `c = {};` is an error. You could do `test::test(): c() {}`, or `test::test(): c{} {}`.

Comment: @DeiDei I am not sure what you meant by that. Like what am I supposed to replace the comment line with?

Comment: @M.M both of them work! Thanks for your help! But what kind of syntax is that tho? As I have already mentions I am new to C++. I have never come across such a declaration. Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @user6771484: Read about [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) & [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

Comment: @user6771484 look up in whatever book or learning resource you are using, where it discusses initialization. This is pretty basic

Answer (score 0):

```
test::test()
{
    // declaring a local variable
    int c[6][6] = { 0 };

    // initializing the actual matrix
    for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++)
        for (int q = 0; q < 6; q++)
            this->c[r][q] = 0;

    // this is a pointer to the object
    // local c & this->c are two different variables
}
```